# White screen when launching android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I launch my android emulator, in addition to the white screen it gives me this error:

> Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\user.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_26.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied

The Emulator looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I found the solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaEKeETxwsY ...